# How to update remains balance to next record using Php for loop?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, for-loop

Can anybody help me to solve this? For example, I have 273 total stocks and a balance remaining as 263 in the database record. I need 10 more for completed. But if I entered **12** it should add as 263+10 in this record and another remaining 2 should go next record as my paper_stock query. But the first record 10 add and save without problem, but the next one added as **68** I don't understand why?

```
$enterdQty = 12; 
        
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $enterdQty; $i++) {
            $paper_stock = paper_stock::where('paper_id', $pid)->where('status', 0)->whereRaw('balance < qty')->first();
           //first time $paper_stock->qty = 273
           //first time $paper_stock->balance = 263

            $paper_stock->balance = $paper_stock->balance + $i;
            $paper_stock->save(); 

            if ($paper_stock->qty == $paper_stock->balance) {
                $paper_stock->status = 1;
                $paper_stock->save();
            } 
        }
```

As a summary, I want to update the stock balance and if ented values go to more than the remaining value it should add to the next record balance.

Comment: what do you mean by `next record`?

Comment: Why do you need to use a loop

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you tried debugging, even with vardump, where does the script start to go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've improved your code what I guess from your question. Try this one. I hope it will work.

```
$enterdQty = 12;

//for ($i = 0; $i <= $enterdQty; $i++) {
$paper_stock = paper_stock::where('paper_id', $pid)->where('status', 0)->whereRaw('balance < qty')->first();
//first time $paper_stock->qty = 273
//first time $paper_stock->balance = 263

if ($paper_stock->qty == $paper_stock->balance) {
    $paper_stock->status = 1;
    $paper_stock->save();
}else{
    $stock_diff = $paper_stock->qty - $paper_stock->balance;

    if ($stock_diff > $enterdQty) {
        $paper_stock->balance = $paper_stock->balance + $stock_diff;
        $paper_stock->save();

        $remaining_stock = $enterdQty - $stock_diff;
        $paper_stock = paper_stock::where('paper_id', $pid)->where('status', 0)->whereRaw('balance < qty')->first();
        $paper_stock->balance = $paper_stock->balance + $remaining_stock;
        $paper_stock->save();
    } else {
        $paper_stock->balance = $paper_stock->balance + $stock_diff;
        $paper_stock->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've figured out the issue, and the below code is working for me. Thanks a lot for helping me.

```
            $enterdQty = $this->balance; 
    
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $enterdQty; $i++) {
                $paper_stock = paper_stock::where('paper_id', $pid)->where('status', 0)->whereRaw('balance < qty')->first();
                $check[] = $i;
                $paper_stock->balance = $paper_stock->balance + 1;
    
                $paper_stock->save();
    
                if ($paper_stock->qty == $paper_stock->balance) {
                    $paper_stock->status = 1;
                    $paper_stock->save();
                    $enterdQty = $enterdQty - $i;
                    $i = 0;
                }
            }
```